# Tezos main net node: Hardware specs

Tags: node, baking, setup, solo-baking

Good afternoon,

What are the hardware requirements for a tezos node?  I have a 2 core cpu with 16 gigs of ram for my baker.  I'm trying to decide on what type of single-board computer to buy to run my node.

Comment: You can run Tezos on a Rpi3, https://github.com/maxtez-raspbaker/tezos-rpi3/wiki

Answer (score 8):

- CPU: nothing special, a couple of GHz will do, tezos supports
  multi-core well
- MEMORY: see my plot below. Seems like >4GB makes sense.
  8GB should be enough.
- STORAGE: Random read and random write >150MB/s. This can easily become a bottleneck with embedded systems, a spinning disk is not recommended. Also flash cards could wear out
  quickly if they are not industrial grade.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

8GB RAM is recommended<sup>[1](https://medium.com/tezos/its-a-baker-s-life-for-me-c214971201e1#cfbe)</sup> for a node. Kiln recommends 10GB of RAM for example. The mainnet node in my Ubuntu 18.04 Baker/Node doesn't use up a lot of resources from the CPU. However, using an SSD is highly recommended. I at least have been getting a lot of "timed out" errors on the second node I run on an HDD. The mainnet node running on an SSD runs smooth.

### End of 2023 Update:

I forgot to mention that running on RAID0 with 3 HDDs or RAID10 with 4 HDDs should also work fine. Nowadays the memory usage is really low, so 8GB should suffice.

Comment: Thats cool, I guess I could run both my baker and my mainnet on the same node then since I have 16gb of ram and 500gb hdd, I was just worried about my baker missing block if I ran both on one computer.

Comment: Just be aware that restarting a tezos-node on a HDD might take a very long time with the current implementation. The node has to go through the chain to find the current valid head. This can take up to half an hour or more depending on the hardware.

Comment: Memory usage has been/will be improved https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/tezos/commit/7dfb9b7fd387120389cc010d19f80e4022f08509 8GB of RAM is still big overkill, even for running node/baker/endorser all on same system.

Answer (score 3):

We run our node on Digital Ocean. Our nodes are 2vCPU/2GB RAM/60GB SSD with 4GB swap. We have been running this configuration for 6+ months with no issues. We used to run with 1vCPU, but had lots of iowait. A second vCPU solved that. SSD is almost a must-have. Anything over >4GB RAM or >2 CPUs/Cores is just overkill at this time. Maybe in 1-2+ years when there are more smart contracts running you'll need the additional CPU capacity.

Comment: Our CPU usage for past week: https://i.imgur.com/bUebQzL.png

Answer (score 1):

I've been running a baker on a raspberry pi with 4CPU's and 4 gigs of ram for no issues.  Also running a node on vultr(cloud provider) for testnet,  2 cpu with 4 gigs of ram, no issues at all running a baker on testnet there as well.