# Why does the Tezos node use only one CPU core?

Tags: node, setup

I never see the Tezos node using more than CPU core even when syncing from scratch. Why is this? Is this the reason why the nodes takes forever to sync in archive mode? Are there any plans to make the node multi-threaded or more performant?

Answer (score 3):

The performance of syncing an archive node depends on multiple factors including your hardware, network connectivity, number peers etc however one of the dominant one is the intensity of I/O operations not the number of computations by the CPU (see [this question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/tezos-main-net-node-hardware-specs/1119#1119) for instance). It is more likely that you would go faster by improving your storage from say hdd to ssd than by having the node go from single threaded to multithreaded.

To fasten up syncing there are several alternatives

1) use [snapshots](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/snapshots.html): see [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/available-snapshots-for-main-net) and [there](https://medium.com/tezos/https-medium-com-tezos-spinning-up-a-tezos-node-in-under-a-few-minutes-3b3328e173f3) for additional infos

2) use a different [history mode](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/history_modes.html) : see [this answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/486/118) for more infos

Comment: Thanks for the information but this doesn't answer my questions about only a single CPU core being used.

Comment: @tezette the tezos node is single threaded afaik so it uses only 1 cpu core.

Comment: I am more interested in why and whether there's any plans to change it?

Comment: @tezette what makes you think its necessart for the node to be multithreaded ?

Comment: For the same benefits we get from multithreading any application on a modern processor.