# What are the minimum requirements ( Hardware ) for being a Baker and get listed on MyTezosBaker?

Tags: baking, mytezosbaker

Wanted to have a solo baking setup, do we need to carry out some task for verification of transactions?
Or we just need to set up a node running and it will do it all alone

Comment: For MyTezosBaker, I suggest you contact them directly, which is what their website suggests: info@mytezosbaker.com. In terms of h/w reqs, have a look at the following question: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/tezos-main-net-node-hardware-specs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tezos main net node: Hardware specs](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/tezos-main-net-node-hardware-specs)